# xml parsing using xmltextreader

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I am parsing some xml entries using the xmltextreader and looking for the elements I need by using different textreaders for each in a different loop as follows:

```
Dim treader As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader(New StringReader(item.ToString))
                While treader.Read
                    If treader.Name = "summary" Then
                        content = treader.ReadElementContentAsString
                        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(content) Then
                            content = "NOTHING"
                            Continue While
                        End If
                        contentList.Add(content)
                        Exit While

                    End If
                End While
```

and I do the same for each element I am looking for. Now the problem arises when I get the results for each. I use an arraylist for each element and at times I will have an unequal amount like 100 for summary, 100 for title , 99 for id etc...
is there a more efficient way of doing this by checking the entry if all the nodes are there and then just skipping it if it's not.

```
<entry>
 <summary>
 <id>
 <published>
 <uri>
 <rule>
</entry>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make an entry object and deserialize the xml as a list of entry objects.  That would open the door to linq and for each loops.  Check out the [XmlSerializer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx).  I hope your data doesn't have 99 ids and 100 of some other field.

Comment: thanks for your response, will try that. The difference in counts is more due to some reader error in one of the while loops and it then skips the others. If a detect a problem with the entry I just add that to a separate list.